# Check if true or false on json parse into html

Tags: javascript, json

Currently have all data displaying perfectly except the boolean ones.
I have some data that if `true` or `false` they should display different html/css

So, how can I have a class or html that shows the data if returns true?

I'm a bit stuck on parsing this data on this code. As I was on the right direction until this new request.

The Json loooks like this:

```
{ 
    "name": "Serena Gosling",
    "supporterNumber": "0123456789",
    "isStrongRelationship": true,
    "ticketingPoints" :"2,500 Ticket Points",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://i.pravatar.cc/100"
},
```

```js
fetch("supporters.json")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(supporters => {
    localStorage.setItem("supporters", JSON.stringify(supporters));
  });

let container = document.querySelector(".content");
let loadMoreButton = document.querySelector(".content button");

let initialItems = 4;
let loadItems = 2;

function loadInitialItems() {
  let supporters = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("supporters"));
  let out = "";
  let counter = 0;
  for (let supporter of supporters) {
    if (counter < initialItems) {
      out += `
            <div class="supporter">
            <h4 class="supporter__name">
            <span class="supporter__thumbnail"></span>
              ${supporter.name}
              ${supporter.relationship} 
              <span class="supporter__number">(${supporter.supporterNumber})</span>
            </h4>
            <span class="supporter__points">${supporter.ticketingPoints}</span>
          </div>
            `;
    }
    counter++;
  }

  let div = document.createElement("div");
  container.insertBefore(div, loadMoreButton);
  div.innerHTML = out;
}

function loadData() {
  let supporters = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("supporters"));
  let currentDisplayedItems = document.querySelectorAll(".supporter").length;

  let out = "";
  let counter = 0;
  for (let supporter of supporters) {
    if (counter >= currentDisplayedItems && counter < loadItems + currentDisplayedItems) {
      out += `
            <div class="supporter">
            <h4 class="supporter__name">
            <span class="supporter__thumbnail"></span>
              ${supporter.name}
              ${supporter.relationship} 
              <span class="supporter__number">(${supporter.supporterNumber})</span>
            </h4>
            <span class="supporter__points">${supporter.ticketingPoints}</span>
          </div>
            `;
    }
    counter++;
  }

  let div = document.createElement("div");
  container.insertBefore(div, loadMoreButton);
  div.innerHTML = out;
  div.style.opacity = 0;

  if (document.querySelectorAll(".supporter").length == supporters.length) {
    loadMoreButton.style.display = "none";
  }

  fadeIn(div);
}

function fadeIn(div) {
  let opacity = 0;
  let interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (opacity <= 1) {
      opacity = opacity + 0.1;
      div.style.opacity = opacity;
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 30);
}

loadInitialItems()
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <!-- content displaye from the javascript file -->

  <button onclick="loadData()" class="load-more-button"><span>&#10093;</span> </button>
</div>
```

Comment: on which line the problem actually is?

Comment: @himanshurajora don't have a problem on the code, code isn't there yet. I need to check if data returns true or false

Comment: Just use an `if` statement that tests the boolean element.

Comment: if, thanks, I know the if statement should do the job but how? I've added a bit of the json in here.

Comment: Or use a ternary expression, e.g. `${supporter.isStrongRelationship ? "Strong" : "Weak"}`

Comment: Where are you trying to actually test the boolean value? What have you tried?

Comment: @user173420 data is already plural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ternary expression in the template literal.

```
      out += `
            <div class="supporter">
            <h4 class="supporter__name">
            <span class="supporter__thumbnail"></span>
              ${supporter.name}
              ${supporter.relationship} 
              <span class="supporter__number">(${supporter.supporterNumber})</span>
            </h4>
            <span class="supporter__points">${supporter.ticketingPoints}</span>
            <span class="supporter__relationship">${supporter.isStrongRelationship ? "Strong" : "Weak"} relationship</span>
          </div>
            `;
```

Comment: it returns undefined, any idea why?

Comment: There's no `relationship` property in your JSON, what are you expecting for `supporter.relationship`. That seems to be unrelated to the question about the boolean `isStrongRelationship` property.

Comment: `"isStrongRelationship": true` this one

Comment: I guess you should remove `${supporter.relationship}` and just use my addition.